# Why am I getting marked down, and about to get banned

Tags: discussion, support

This website is to help people right? I try to explain my questions the best way I can, however I see where I am about to be banned from asking questions on stackoverflow. Well I am not a professional, that is why I am here. I am not abusing the website, so I do not see why I am "about to get banned" I do not understand this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Make sure you look at this and respect it :). I don't know your particular questions, but in general, the fact that you need an answer doesn't necessarily mean your question is good or should be asked here. Stack Overflow became good because it filters bad content away

Comment: I have read that already, and searching the website to see what is the problem. The question I asked last night nothing was wrong with it, but people choose to mark me down.

Comment: Clearly you aren't asking very good questions. Looking at your most (recent) heavily downvoted one, it reads a lot more like a "How do I implement this feature" than a programming question. It might help if you asked why a specific post that you think is good is considered "bad"

Comment: See @Crisp, I took a second to look at your questions. I see too broad, poorly researched stuff all around, honestly. "how do I do a drop down list on keyboard hit", with NO tries from you, you even ask "can I be directed to where I can find this info", when it's clearly off-topic for Stack.... go read thoroughly the help articles and make sure you respect them :)

Comment: SO users did not vote on you, they voted on your question.  We are not here to help you, we want to help the next 100 programmers that have the same problem.  The Q+A you created is pretty unlikely to accomplish that, thus the votes.  You don't have a single positively scored contribution, so yes, a question ban is a pretty likely outcome.

Comment: We vote on the quality of questions. The last question you asked on SO was *Is there a code for this? and could I be directed to where I can get this information?*, which is simply a terrible question. The answer is quite easy: *Yes, there is code for this, and you can be directed to it by Google.*. We're not tutors or link locators, and we're not anyone's personal research assistants, and the question as asked has no meaningful value to future readers here. We're trying to share information that will help lots of people in the future - we're not here to solve one person's problem for them.

Comment: We understand that there are people who are not pros, but we assume a minimum of knowledge, and want the Q&A combos on this site to be useful not just to you but to others too. But you've posted no less than 6 (!) Matlab questions all tightly connected to just 1 of your `numbas`-processing programs! [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853087), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084025), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982555), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172857), [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368161), [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187468).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I admit I didn't look at OP questions, I just sorta assumed suckage.

Comment: @MartinJames I somehow managed to miss two of them: [7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600492) and [8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203928), so 8/18 questions are just on "`numbas`". @Crisp I believe you post in good faith, but this website is simply not for personalized, 1-on-1 Matlab help (chat.stackoverflow.com might? be a better place for that?). 8 questions on a single program suggests to me that you actually need a Matlab tutorial, or some time spent talking with profs/TAs/peers/friends. It is not right to leave many questions whose answers will only ever be useful to you.

Answer (score 24):

Let's look at [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360316/drop-down-list-upon-key-entry):

> #### drop down list upon key entry
>
> I am interested in creating a drop down list upon key entry from a sql database. There are many examples given here for a drop down list however I am not just interested in that, I want the user input to initiate the drop down and it narrows down to the result with each additional entries. It is similar to facebook search and youtube search and some other popular websites. This is very efficient for a database with a large number data within a list.
>
> eg. The user wants to enter Dog for animal name, and in my sql list for animals beginning wih "d" I have dog, dolphin, donkey, deer,...etc.
>   Now when the User enters "d", dog, dolphin, donkey, deer,...etc would come up, and when they enter "o", (by now they would have "do") the list would just change to just dog, donkey, dolphin.
>
> Is there a code for this? and could I be directed to where I can get this information?
>
> [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)

For a change, I'm not going to critique it. I'm just going to describe what goes through my head as I read it...

1. **Title:** You want a drop-down list to appear when a key is pressed. Slightly odd, but presumably there's a reason for this requirement that'll become apparent as I read the question. As someone with years of UI-design experience, this question interests me.
2. **First paragraph:** Oh, so... you're talking about an incremental search through a fixed set of options in a dropdown, a.k.a. *filtering*. That's less odd, but also less interesting; this has been a common UI fixture for decades. Nevermind, let's see what's so special about your specific needs that you couldn't use one of the myriad existing libraries to accomplish this...
3. **Second paragraph:** Nothing. You're describing list filtering as implemented in countless libraries and, quite frankly, trivially implemented from scratch by any beginning programmer (albeit usually with some common inefficiencies).
4. **Third paragraph:** you haven't searched. Faaaantastic.

There is a wealth of information already available on Stack Overflow for folks looking to accomplish tasks like this. You're doing yourself a disservice by not doing a trivial amount of research first.

I went ahead and re-closed your question as a duplicate of one that should help you. In the future, try anticipating this and saving yourself - and others - the time it took this time around.

Answer (score 11):

Well, take a look at [your most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28360316/4015623).

I didn't have to read almost any of it. As soon as my eyes hit the last line that you wrote, I knew the question was innapproporiate for StackOverflow. You write,

> Is there a code for this? and could I be directed to where I can get this information?

That is already not really in the spirit of the site. When I read over the rest of the question, it all came together - it is broad, not very clear, and you're basically just asking for code.

I recommend you look at the [How to Ask help link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, look at the [top questions by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes). They haven't been upvoted thousands of times for no reason. See how they present their question and what kind of answers those questions generate.

To address your last concern, as you say:

> I am not abusing the website, so I do not see why I am "about to get banned"

You may think that you aren't abusing the website, as it's true that you aren't posting spam or flagging a million posts to gum up the queue, but in reality, **posting poor-quality questions does hurt the site**. Anything asking for code the way your last question does isn't going to be useful down the road for other people.

As a final note, though this all may come off a bit harshly, it certainly isn't meant to be a personal attack. It's just very important to understand what's appropriate for the site and what isn't. You can post answers or higher-quality questions to get more rep and move away from the ban-cliff.